# Need T-SQL query to get multiple choice answer if matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Example:

Table `Question_Answers`:

```
    +------+--------+
    | q_id | ans_id |
    +------+--------+
    |    1 |      2 |
    |    1 |      4 |
    |    2 |      1 |
    |    3 |      1 |
    |    3 |      2 |
    |    3 |      3 |
    +------+--------+
```

`User_Submited_Answers`:

```
    | q_id | sub_ans_id |
    +------+------------+
    |    1 |          2 |
    |    1 |          4 |
    |    2 |          1 |
    |    3 |          1 |
    |    3 |          2 |
    |    3 |          4 |
    +------+------------+
```

I need a T-SQL query if this rows matches count 1 else 0

Comment: What output do you want here?  It appears that each question has more than one answer.

Comment: its a multiple answer question, one mark for each question, if the user submitted answer matches with question answers then i should get  no of correct questions user has submited

Comment: Why is a user submitting _multiple_ answers for a question?  What is your expected output?  Can you answer my questions?

Comment: What you want to achive? as @TimBiegeleisen said why is a user submiting multiple answer?

Comment: because its a multiple choice question we are displaying more then 3 options for single question in a checkbox  user will mark multiple options

Comment: This is relational division.

Comment: If you add desirable output, it will help us, to help you

Comment: I have copied my answer I gave to the exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423830/multiple-choice-answer-t-sql-query/43424219#43424219).  If this works for you and accept it we can mark the other question as exact duplicate of this one (or vice versa).

Comment: So @manip what are you and Lokesh stydying?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis `I have copied my answer` ... no, don't do that.  If this is a dupe, then mark it as such.  Actually, you should mark it as being unclear, as it is a homework dump showing zero effort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, I think that when a question is closed as duplicate the text "the question already has an answer here" is presented; the problem is that the guy asking for his homework didn't bother to accept the answer, so we don't know if the question does have an answer already!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis You asked to be marked correct on a question which should probably be closed.  That doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nobody voted (at least explicitly) for the question to be closed, and I took the time (as other people did, including you!) to asnwer it. Now either we decide to close these questions, or we find a correct answer and mark these as duplicates. Either way I am fine with it. On the other hand, I think the question is interesting by itself, and SO users might benefit from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple choice answer T-SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423830/multiple-choice-answer-t-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.q_id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.sub_ans_id) = COUNT(*)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END AS is_correct
FROM Question_Answers t1
LEFT JOIN User_Submited_Answers t2
    ON t1.q_id   = t2.q_id AND
       t1.ans_id = t2.sub_ans_id
GROUP BY t1.q_id
```

Comment: not like this i want to get no of question user submitted correct answer example :  q_id 3 has 3 correct option user submitted 1 wrong answer for this marks count 0

Comment: getting error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: I was missing an `END` in the `CASE` expression, sorry.

Comment: ok thank you, i am getting wrong when this case: question_answers  options are 2 and user submitted answers are 3, its giving 1 instead of 0

Comment: Show us the actual output you want.  I have answered as I understand the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen seems like there is more `Multiple answers` today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423830/multiple-choice-answer-mssqlquery

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
select qa.q_id,case when qa.ans_id=sqa.ans_id then 1 else 0 end as result from questionans qa
left  join subquestionans sqa
on qa.q_id=sqa.q_id and qa.ans_id=sqa.ans_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you expected result for every question.

```
select q_id, min(Is_Correct)Is_Correct from (
select Q.q_id,case when count(A.sub_ans_id)=count(*) then 1 else 0 end as Is_Correct
from #Q Q left join #A A on Q.q_id=A.q_id and Q.ans_id=A.sub_ans_id
group by Q.q_id
UNION ALL
select A.q_id,case when count(Q.ans_id)=count(*) then 1 else 0 end as Is_Correct
from #Q Q right join #A A on Q.q_id=A.q_id and Q.ans_id=A.sub_ans_id
group by A.q_id ) I group by q_id
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL solution ([sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b20906/6)):

```
SELECT tmp.q_id, MIN(c) as correct
FROM (
    SELECT qa.q_id, IF(qa.q_id = usa.q_id, 1, 0) as c 
    FROM question_answers qa
    LEFT JOIN user_submited_answers usa
      ON qa.q_id = usa.q_id AND qa.ans_id = usa.sub_ans_id
    UNION
    SELECT usa.q_id, IF(qa.q_id = usa.q_id, 1, 0) as c 
    FROM question_answers qa
    RIGHT JOIN user_submited_answers usa
      ON qa.q_id = usa.q_id AND qa.ans_id = usa.sub_ans_id
) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.q_id;
```

Now, step by step explanation:

In order to get the right output we will need to:

- extract from `question_answers` table the answers which were not filled in by the user (in your example: `q_id = 3` with `ans_id = 3`)
- extract from `user_submited_answers` table the wrong answers which were filled in by the user (in your example: `q_id = 3` with `sub_ans_id = 4`)

To do that we can use a full outer join (for mysql left join + right join):

```
SELECT *
FROM question_answers qa
LEFT JOIN user_submited_answers usa
  ON qa.q_id = usa.q_id AND qa.ans_id = usa.sub_ans_id
UNION
SELECT *
FROM question_answers qa
RIGHT JOIN user_submited_answers usa
  ON qa.q_id = usa.q_id AND qa.ans_id = usa.sub_ans_id;
```

From the previous query results, the rows which we are looking for (wrong answers) contains NULL values (based on the case, in `question_answers` table or `user_submited_answers` table).

The next step is to mark those rows with 0 (wrong answer) using an IF or CASE statement: `IF(qa.q_id = usa.q_id, 1, 0)`.

To get the final output we need to group by `q_id` and look for 0 values in the grouped rows. If there is at least one 0, the answer for that question is wrong and it should be marked as that.

Check sql fiddle: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b20906/6)