# Multiple choice answer T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Query is to get whether the user selected multiple choice answer for a question is right or not, if correct then 1 else 0

I have two tables `question_answer` and `user_exam_answer`, entries table has the user submitted answer in column `submitted_option_id`

[user_exam_answer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRaTM.png)

[question_answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N58eU.png)

I tried to write a query when user answer (`user_exam_answer`) matches with the question answer (`question_answer`) table

```
select 
    count(1) as result 
from 
    (select 
         qa.question_id, 
         count(qa.correct_option_id) as col1, 
         count(sa.submited_option_id) as col2 
     from 
         question_answer qa
     left join 
         user_exam_answers sa on (sa.question_id = qa.question_id 
                                  and sa.submited_option_id = qa.correct_option_id 
                                  and sa.exam_id = 'html_001' 
                                  and sa.user_id = 'user_123')
     group by 
         qa.question_id
     having 
         count(qa.correct_option_id) = count(sa.submited_option_id) 
 ) as t
```

But the problem is when:

- QA (question_answer.correct_option_id) has 3 entries and SA user_exam_answers.submited_option_id) has 2 entries then the query is correct and returns
- QA (question_answer.correct_option_id) has 2 entries and SA (user_exam_answers.submited_option_id) is 3 entries then the query is correct and returns
- QA (question_answer.correct_option_id) has 2 entries SA (user_exam_answers.submited_option_id) has 1 entry then the query is correct and returns

**but** when

- QA (question_answer.correct_option_id) has 1 entries and  SA (user_exam_answers.submited_option_id) has 2 entries then the query returns the **wrong** answer

I am looking for a query which holds true for all the four condition

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your conditions **giving examples?** And provide schema (`create table`) and data (`insert into ...)` in text, not picture.

Comment: in the image link you can see the entries

Comment: @Lokesh Don't post code as pictures , post it as it is (Text) please

Comment: If a student does not attempt an answer are they deemed to have gotten it wrong or are you only interested in tracking the results of the attempted answers?

Comment: Can more than one answer exits for a multiple choice question?  If so do they generate as many points as correct Answers for that question or do they have to get all to score the single point associated with that question?

Comment: If the student doenot answer then the count should be 0

Comment: @Lokesh welcome to SO, if you plan to stay please learn how to ask good questions, and help the community help you (and perhaps vice versa). Three people have already taken the time to answer, and you could have helped us a lot if you had provided the table schema, sample data, and clear description of your scenarios.

Comment: Based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423430/need-t-sql-query-to-get-multiple-choice-answer-if-matches which mysteriously appeared at almost the same time, I'd say some questions require multiple answers, and the user gets the a point for the question if, and only if, they select all and only the correct answers. Sadly that makes my answer below wrong. Lokesh, please confirm. And does @GiorgosAltanis 's answer work for you? If so, please accept it.

Comment: Well, this is what I tried to implement. If our interpretation is correct, perhaps we should edit the question to have this information. By the way @SteveLovell do you think my answer is correct?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, it took me a while to get my head round the full-outer-join, but having done so, I reckon your answer is correct. Upvoting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very unclear what you're trying to do here, but the below should help get you started:

```
select
    sa.user_id,
    sa.exam_id,
    qa.question_id,
    sa.submitted_option_id,
    qa.correct_option_id,
    case when sa.submitted_option_id = qa.correct_option_id then 1 else 0 end as question_score
from
    question_answer qa     
    LEFT JOIN user_exam_answer sa ON
        uea.question_id = qa.question_id
where
    sa.exam_id='html_001'
    and sa.user_id='user_123'
```

I'd expect the `qa` table to also have an `exam_id` column, but that isn't in your images.

Answer (score 3):

For each question list the expected answers and the submitted answers (you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to do this, a `LEFT` join is not enough) and count the number of matches. Then compare this count with the count of the expected answers.

```
select question_id, case when cnt = sum_test then 1 else 0 end as mark
from (
    select question_id, count(*) cnt, sum(test) sum_test
    from (
        select coalesce(q.question_id, s.question_id) as question_id, 
        correct_option_id, 
        submitted_option_id, 
        case when correct_option_id = submitted_option_id then 1 else 0 end as test
        from question_answer q full outer join user_exam_answer s 
        on q.question_id = s.question_id and q.correct_option_id = s.submitted_option_id
        ) x
    group by question_id
) y
```

You can find a [live demo here](http://rextester.com/XIVKZK8912)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT user_id,
       exam_id,
       question_answer.question_id AS question_id,
       submited_option_id,
       correct_option_id,
       CASE
           WHEN correct_option_id = submited_option_id THEN
               1
           ELSE
               0
       END AS marked_option_id
FROM question_answer
LEFT JOIN user_exam_answer ON question_answer.question_id = user_exam_answer.question_id
ORDER BY user_id,
         exam_id,
         question_id;
```

This query performs joins the two tables together using a `LEFT JOIN` so that a record for an an unanswered question is still returned.  It then compares the correct answer to the supplied answer for each record and if they match it returns a value of `1`, otherwise it will return a value of `0`.  The results of this comparison are then included in the output as the field `marked_option_id`.  The resulting output is then sorted for convenience of reading.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.